# How to determine whether a given compound is paramagnetic or diamagnetic?

Tags: bond, magnetism

Well i am very confused whether we can determine the magnetic property of compounds..

If it us asked for elements we can say by looking at electronic configuration...

For ex- 
how is N2O diamagnetic?
How is NO paramagnetic?
How is NO2 paramagnetic?
What about N2O5

Comment: It's just the same: you look at the molecular orbitals and the electronic configuration. Before that, do a quick check: if the thing has an odd number of electrons, it is surely paramagnetic. If the number is even, it is _likely_ diamagnetic, though exceptions do exist. Also, welcome to Chem.SE.

Comment: Paramagnetism is a consequence of having one or more un-paired electrons in the outer electronic configuration. e.g. O2, and NO. Most phys. chem. or inorganic chemistry textbooks will explain this in detail.

Answer (score 2):

Paramagnetism is a consequence of having one or more un-paired electrons in the outer electronic configuration. e.g. O$_2$, and NO. 
An an odd number of electrons can clearly produce a paramagnetic ion, radical or molecule. However, molecules with an *even* number of electrons can also be paramagnetic, the most famous being dioxygen (O$_2$). The experimental observation is that oxygen is attracted to a magnet.(This is best observed with liquid oxygen.) Nitrogen (N$_2$) is not paramagnetic but diamagnetic. 
 Whether a molecule is paramagnetic or not is only explained using molecular orbital theory. In the case of O$_2$ it is found that the lowest energy state is one that has one electron in each of two orbitals. An alternative would be to expend energy to pair up these two electrons into one orbital. As this requires energy it does not occur. 
High and low spin transition metal complexes show the same effect of pairing vs. placing electrons into different orbitals.

Comment: ‘As this requires energy it does not occur.’ Hm. Singlet oxygen does exist and can be liberated given the correct reaction conditions. Photons are emitted when singlet oxygen transforms into triplet oxygen.

Answer (score 1):

Paramagnetism is a result of unpaired electrons. If we count the valence electrons available to the four species you name, we can take a pretty quick guess as to what might be paramagnetic. If the species has an odd number of electrons, it must be paramagnetic. If the species has an even number of electrons, it is likely diamagetic.

For example, $\ce{NO}$ has 11 valence electrons. One of them must be unpaired.

Can you work out the others?